# Problems understand preprocessing steps that turn images into the format of MNIST dataset

Tags: python, matlab, machine-learning, dataset

I want to make a program that turns a given image into the format of the MNIST dataset, as a kind of exercise to understand the various preprocessing steps involved. But the description the authors made on their site: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ was not entirely straightforward:

> The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size
>   normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect
>   ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the
>   anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the
>   images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass
>   of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point
>   at the center of the 28x28 field.

So from the original I have to normalize it to fit a 20x20 box, and still preserving their aspect ratio (I think they mean the aspect ratio of the actual digit, not the entire image). Still I really don't know how to do this.

Center of mass: I have found some online code about this, but I don't think I understand the principle. Here is my take on this: The coordinate of each pixel is actually a vector from the origin to that point, so for each point you multiply the coordinate with the image intensity, then sum everything, before dividing by the total intensity of the image. I may be wrong about this :(

Translating the image so as to position this point at the center: Maybe cook up some translation equation, or maybe use a convolutional filter to facilitate translation, then find a path that leads to the center (Dijikstra's shortest path ?).

All in all, I think i still need guidance on this. Can anyone explain about these parts for me ? Thank you very much. 
I think

Comment: Isn't the MNIST dataset pictures of handwritten digits ?

Comment: What does "the format of the MNIST dataset" mean? 28x28 pixels? Grey scale? Etc.

Comment: I think the OP maybe referring to the trained ivectors for the recognition data set...but who knows, could be pink unicorn

Comment: @Alex Yes 28x28 pixels, and grescale. But the images must go through the type of preprocessing mentioned in the authors' site: "The original black and white (bilevel) images from NIST were size normalized to fit in a 20x20 pixel box while preserving their aspect ratio. The resulting images contain grey levels as a result of the anti-aliasing technique used by the normalization algorithm. the images were centered in a 28x28 image by computing the center of mass of the pixels, and translating the image so as to position this point at the center of the 28x28 field. " .

Comment: @GameOfThrows I'm just trying to learn the preprocessing steps, that's all. Nothing about training here, just the preprocessing step. I mean, you have a PNG image of the handwritten digit "5", and you want to find out how to convert it into MNIST format. But I don't understand all of the authors' explanation so as a last resort I decided it would be better to study someone else ' code :(

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't support questions asking for external resources, so asking for a link to sample program is not on-topic. Is there any way to re-phrase the question so that it is about your attempts to replicate the processing as described (ideally with Python code so far)?

Comment: Not exactly your question, but the duplicate tells you how to revert the MNIST data format into actual image data. Simply apply the reverse steps.

Comment: It is better, and reading the "duplicate" I think I disagree with raryreng that you can get what you want from the the answers there, as it is about the numerical part, not the image manipulation. So, voting to re-open. You may want to add some detail to "Center of mass: I think i have a rough idea about this" because a valid answer there would skip that part and you may have it wrong. You definitely have gone in the wrong direction with the translation - the actual technique is very simple vector offset.

Comment: @NeilSlater No one else wants a revote? :(

Comment: Question has collected 2 reopen votes so far.

Comment: @NeilSlater And now ? :(

Comment: It's down to 1 :-( I've never seen that before . . .

Comment: I think the duplicate is in error, and the explanations are enough to put the question on-topic. But I don't have any way to undo the closure alone - it needs other people (I think 3 more) to pay attention to the question and agree with me. The problem is most likely lack of attention - one way of getting attention would be to post on meta and ask for advice on improving the question further. Some people will agree with me, some may not - but usually this is appreciated and can help you get a better question *and* a better answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ if you want to try that

Comment: @NeilSlater I've reopened. Hope this question gets more attention. OP: Good luck.

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you good sir!